# tag inside bootstrap_button tag in django-bootstrap4

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, django-templates, django-bootstrap4

I have a question regarding the bootstrap_button template tag of django-bootstrap4 (https://django-bootstrap4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templatetags.html#bootstrap-button) , could it be possible to include a tag from my tags in the href, something like this :

`{% bootstrap_button "Supprimer" button_type="link" href="../../delete/{{article.id}} " button_class="btn-danger" %}`
but `{{article.id}}` is not interpreted and it gives me a link to [http://127.0.0.1:8000/delete/{{article.id}}](http://127.0.0.1:8000/delete/%7B%7Barticle.id%7D%7D)

I also tried :

`{% bootstrap_button "Supprimer" button_type="link" href="{% url 'delete' article.id %}" button_class="btn-danger" %}`

it returns

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /edit/127/

Could not parse the remainder: '"{%' from '"{%'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/edit/127/
Django Version:     3.0.5
Exception Type:     TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    

Could not parse the remainder: '"{%' from '"{%'
```

but none of those syntax are not working...
Could you help me to make it works ?

Man thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to declare the url as a template variable first:

```
{% url 'delete' article.id as delete_url %}
{% bootstrap_button "Supprimer" button_type="link" href=delete_url button_class="btn-danger" %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
That looks neat, but it is not working... as there is no double-quote around delete_url the button is not rendered as an ``<a>``.
And if I add double-quote I got a link to delete_url (with no remplacement of its value)

Comment: Did you check the rendered html from the console? The anchor would look like a button (css) but would be an anchor.

Comment: yes it give me this ```<button class="btn btn-danger">Supprimer</button>```

Comment: Try rendering `{{ delete_url }}` separately does it give anything?

Comment: sorry, my mistake... I had a trouble my urls
Thank you so much

Comment: How did you resolve this? I'm trying to render the following: `{% bootstrap_button "Button" href="{{ foo }}" %}` where foo is `{% url 'foo' as foo %}`. But the anchor tag renders as `<a href="{{ foo }}" role="button">Button</a>` (so not a valid href)

Comment: @James You just need to write `{% bootstrap_button "Button" href=foo %}`. The `{{}}` syntax doesn't work inside a template tag and variables can be referred directly.